# Combining spacebelow with shaded parameter in thmtools package. Bug?

Tags: spacing, theorems, thmtools

In the following example the spacebelow parameter is ignored. If you comment out the shaded parameter, the space is considered. Is it possible to use both parameters spacebelow / shaded?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=6pt,
    spacebelow=60pt,
    shaded={bgcolor={rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}}
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{BoxI}

\begin{document}
\begin{BoxI}[Euclid]
  Text...
\end{BoxI}
Some text...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `shaded` seems to effect both `spaceabove` and `spacebelow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (in my version on page 5) says that `thmbox` and `shaded` keys may

> not cooperate with a style key you give at the same time.

**EDIT**

The following solution was offered by @GonzaloMedina.  Since Gonzalo suggested I post his answer here, I'm making this a community wiki

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheoremstyle[mdframed={backgroundcolor=gray!80, 
                               hidealllines=true, 
                               innertopmargin=6pt, 
                               innerbottommargin=60pt, 
                               skipabove=\topsep, 
                               skipbelow=\topsep } 
                    ]{mystyle} 
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{BoxI} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{BoxI}[Euclid] Text... 
\end{BoxI} 
Some text... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess the problem is that the `shaded` style uses the `shadedthm` package which doesn't allow to change the separation between the frame and the text for each side (top, bottom, left, right) individually.

Comment: Yeah, that's the part I was just reading.  Seems there's got to be a work-around.  I'll have to dig into the `shadethm` package.

Comment: Actually it looks like you'll have to dig into the `shadethm.sty` itself since the documentation for it is minimal.

Comment: Yes. You could, for the moment, suggest as a workaround, using the more versatile `mdframed` key: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
mdframed={
  backgroundcolor=gray!80,
  hidealllines=true,
  innertopmargin=6pt,
  innerbottommargin=60pt,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep
}
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{BoxI}

\begin{document}
\begin{BoxI}[Euclid]
  Text...
\end{BoxI}
Some text...
\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sounds like you should post that as your own answer!

Comment: @Medina: this workaround solved my problem! Thx!!!

Comment: @A.Ellett If you want to, add my example to your answer.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the space between the box and the surrounding text? I can either use the "spaceabove"-parameter or the "mdframed"-parameter but not both. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I'm having the same problem. The proposed solution works, but not with AMS classes. Any idea why?