# How to remove space surrounding a colored theorem box?

Tags: spacing, theorems, mdframed, thmtools

This is a follow-up question of [Combining spacebelow with shaded parameter in thmtools package. Bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103879/combining-spacebelow-with-shaded-parameter-in-thmtools-package-bug). How can I get rid of the space above the theorem box? If I comment out the `mdframed=...` line it works, but I also want a nice gray theorem box. Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    mdframed={backgroundcolor=gray!80, hidealllines=true, innertopmargin=6pt, innerbottommargin=60pt, skipabove=\topsep, skipbelow=\topsep },
    spaceabove=0pt, spacebelow=0pt
 ]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{BoxI}

\begin{document}
Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
  \begin{BoxI}[Euclid]
    Text...
  \end{BoxI}
Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this might be a not completely smooth interaction between the packages; `skipbelow` accepts negative values, but `skipabove`, and even `spaceabove` (from `thmtools`) when the `mdframed` key is in action, seem to ignore values that are less than `0pt`. This might have to do with the fact that `thmtools` uses `\addtotheorempreheadhook` to pass the options to the `mdframed` environment.

In any case, you can to use `preheadhook` to control the spacing before the structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
preheadhook={\vskip\dimexpr\topsep-0.5\ht\strutbox\relax},
mdframed={
  backgroundcolor=gray!80,
  hidealllines=true,
  innertopmargin=6pt,
  innerbottommargin=60pt,
  skipabove=0pt,
  skipbelow=\topsep}
 ]{mystyle}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]
{BoxI}

\begin{document}
Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
  \begin{BoxI}[Euclid]
Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
  \end{BoxI}
Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used a `\vskip` of `\topsep-0.5\ht\strutbox`, but of course you can use the desired length according to your needs.